Aiogram из одной и той же функции не отрабатывает корректно
Бот собирает данные и предоставляет пользователю выбор обратной связи: почта, мобильная и телеграмм. Если переходить по кнопкам, то конечный этап - функция last_funс, где пользователю дается выбор подтвердить введенные данные, начать заново или отменить. Если выбирать мобильный номер или почту все корректно отрабатывается, а через телеграмм - зависает и вообще нечего не делает.
import hendlers
import re
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
from create import bot, Dispatcher, dp
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from keyboard import (trc_button, check_invoice, service_selection, callback, send_phone, language_button,
                      confirm_inline_keyboard)
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from hendlers.mail365 import send_mail
from hendlers.handler_start import start_message


class FSMAccounting(StatesGroup):
    sec = State()
    service = State()
    bin = State()
    type_document = State()
    agreement = State()
    period = State()
    callback = State()
    contact = State()
    last = State()

# Стартовые пропустим

# предлагается выбор инлайн кнопками "Телефон" "Емаил" "Телеграмм"
async def reconciliation_periods(message: types.CallbackQuery, state=FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['period'] = message.text
    await FSMAccounting.next()
    await bot.send_message(
        message.from_user.id,
        ' Каким способом Вам будет удобно получить обратную связь?',
        reply_markup=callback
    )

# Проверка на правельность ввода телефона и почты

async def callback_choice(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(callback=callback_query.data)
    if callback_query.data == 'Телефон':
        # Кнопка для отправки номера телефона
        keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
        contact_button = KeyboardButton("Добавить ", request_contact=True)
        keyboard.add(contact_button)

        await FSMAccounting.contact.set()
        await bot.send_message(
            callback_query.from_user.id,
            'Введите свой номер телефона в формате (7 xxx xxxxxxx) или нажмите кнопку ниже:',
            reply_markup=keyboard,
        )
    elif callback_query.data == 'E-mail':
        await FSMAccounting.contact.set()
        await bot.send_message(
            callback_query.from_user.id,
            'Введите адрес электронной почты:'
        )


    # При нажатии кнопки Telegram в FSM уходит его контак и ID в FSM
    elif callback_query.data == 'Telegram':
        user_id = callback_query.from_user.id
        await state.update_data(contact=f"@{callback_query.from_user.username or 'Без имени'} (ID: {user_id})")
        await last_func(callback_query, state) # тут все уходит в финальную фукцию 


# Впроверка вводимых данных на правильный ввод телефона и почты
async def user_contact(message: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    element = await state.get_data()
    print('user_contact')
    if element.get('callback') == 'Телефон':
        print('phone')
        if message.contact:
            phone_number = message.contact.phone_number
            await state.update_data(contact=phone_number)
        elif not message.text.isdigit() or len(message.text) < 10:
            await bot.send_message(
                message.from_user.id,
                'Введите свой номер телефона в формате (7 xxx xxxxxxx)'
            )
            return
        else:
            await state.update_data(contact=message.text)

    elif element.get('callback') == 'E-mail':
        print('mail')
        if not re.match(r"^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+$", message.text):
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите корректный E-mail')
            return
        await state.update_data(contact=message.text)
    print('state.get_data')
    await last_func(message, state) # тут все уходит в финальную фукцию 


# финальная функция в которой вылетают кнопки подтверждения вводимой информации или повторного ввода, 
# почему то если прийти сюда через кнопку Telegram FSM затыкается и дальше не идет
async def last_func(message: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    element = await state.get_data()
    confirm_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    confirm_keyboard.add(
        InlineKeyboardButton("✅ Подтвердить", callback_data="confirm"),
        InlineKeyboardButton(" Заново", callback_data="restart"),
        InlineKeyboardButton("❌ Отмена", callback_data="cancel")
    )
    print(f'{message}\n\n {element}')
    await bot.send_message(
        message.from_user.id,
        f"Ваши данные:\n"
        f"ТРЦ: {element.get('sec', 'Не указано')}\n"
        f"Услуга: {element.get('service', 'Не указано')}\n"
        f"БИН: {element.get('bin', 'Не указано')}\n"
        f"Тип документа: {element.get('type_document', 'Не указано')}\n"
        f"Номер договора: {element.get('agreement', 'Не указано')}\n"
        f"Период сверки: {element.get('period', 'Не указано')}\n"
        f"Контакт: {element.get('contact', 'Не указано')}\n\n"
        f"Вы подтверждаете введённые данные?",
        reply_markup=confirm_keyboard
    )


# финишь FSM  отправка данных на почту
@dp.callback_query_handler(Text(equals="confirm"), state=FSMAccounting.contact)
async def confirm_data(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    print('confirm')
    element = await state.get_data()
    await bot.send_message(
        callback_query.from_user.id,
        "<strong>Ваши данные отправлены:</strong>",
        reply_markup=language_button, parse_mode='HTML'
    )
    send_mail(element)
    await state.finish()
    await callback_query.answer("Данные подтверждены.")


# стоп FSM  старт ее по новой
@dp.callback_query_handler(Text(equals="restart"), state=FSMAccounting.contact)
async def restart_fsm(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await state.finish()
    await FSMAccounting.sec.set()
    await bot.send_message(
        callback_query.from_user.id,
        " Пожалуйста, укажите ТРЦ:",
        reply_markup=trc_button
    )
    await callback_query.answer("Начнем заново.")


# отмена 
@dp.callback_query_handler(Text(equals="cancel"), state=FSMAccounting.contact)
async def cancel_fsm(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await state.finish()
    await bot.send_message(
        callback_query.from_user.id,
        "❌ Действие отменено. Вы можете начать заново.",
        reply_markup=language_button
    )
    await callback_query.answer("Действие отменено.")


def handler_message_accounting(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(callback_choice, state=FSMAccounting.callback)
    dp.register_message_handler(user_contact, state=FSMAccounting.contact, content_types=['text', 'contact'])
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(confirm_data, Text(equals="confirm"), state=FSMAccounting.contact)
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(restart_fsm, Text(equals="restart"), state=FSMAccounting.contact)
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(cansel, Text(equals='cancel', ignore_case=True), state='*')

